# How do I replace a JPanel with GridLayout with another JPanel with GridLayout in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I am working on a project with GridLayout. Currently, I am having trouble replacing a JPanel with GridLayout with another JPanel with GridLayout in my JFrame. Here is the code.

```
    public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public JPanel pan = new JPanel();

    public void replace() {
      frame.remove(pan);
      pan = new JPanel();
      GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8,8);
      pan.setLayout(grid);
      frame.add(pan);
      frame.invalidate();
      frame.revalidate();
      frame.repaint();
    }
```

Much help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: For many components in one space, use a [`CardLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as seen in this [short example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
public JFrame frame = new JFrame();
public JPanel pan = new JPanel();

public void replace() {
  frame.remove(pan);
  pan = new JPanel();
  GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(8,8);
  pan.setLayout(grid);
  pan.setVisible(true);
  frame.add(pan);
  frame.invalidate();
  frame.revalidate();
  frame.repaint();
  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

If not, please, explain what is exactly working wrong for you.